# How to use Inner Join and groupby in the same python code

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-3.7

I have the below input from excel file (**Sheet1** and **Sheet2**)

`Sheet1:`

`Order ID | Order Date | Segment | Sales`

`1001       11-11-2016   Consumer  100`

`1001       11-11-2016   Consumer  200`

`2001       16-06-2016   Consumer  300`

`Sheet2:`

`Returned | Order ID`

`Yes        1001`

And i'm using the below code in python where I'm using the **inner join** and **groupby** to get only the matching records from both the sheets

`import pandas as pd`

`Sheet1 = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Bharath Shana\Desktop\Python\sample data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')`

`Sheet2 = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Bharath Shana\Desktop\Python\sample data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet2')`

`Order_Year = pd.DatetimeIndex(Sheet1['Order Date']).year`

`Sheet1.merge(Sheet2, on='Order ID', how='inner')`

`Sheet1.groupby(['Order ID',Order_Year, 'Segment'])['Sales'].sum()`

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see in the above output instead of showing the matching records it is showing all the records and i want the output like below.

**Required Output:**

[image]

Can someone please help me how to modify my above python code to get the **Required Output**.

Regards,

Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this,

```
print(
    sheet1[sheet1['Order ID'].isin(sheet2['Order ID'])]
        .assign(Year=pd.to_datetime(sheet1['Order Date']).dt.year)
        .groupby(['Order ID', 'Segment', 'Year'])['Sales'].sum()
        .reset_index(name="Sales_Sum")
)
```

---

```
   Order ID   Segment  Year  Sales_Sum
0      1001  Consumer  2016        300
```

Answer (score 2):

In your question you are applying `groupby()` to Sheet1 not to joined Dataframe.

```
s1 = '''Order ID  Order Date  Segment  Sales
1001       11-11-2016   Consumer  100
1001       11-11-2016   Consumer  200
2001       16-06-2016   Consumer  300'''
s2 = '''Returned  Order ID
Yes        1001'''
s1 = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ", l) if t!=""] for l in s1.split("\n") ]
s2 = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ", l) if t!=""] for l in s2.split("\n") ]
Sheet1 = pd.DataFrame(s1[1:], columns=s1[0])
Sheet1["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(Sheet1['Order Date']).year
Sheet1["Sales"] = pd.to_numeric(Sheet1["Sales"])
Sheet2 = pd.DataFrame(s2[1:], columns=s2[0])
Sheet1.merge(Sheet2, on='Order ID', how='inner')\
    .groupby(['Order ID','Year', 'Segment']).agg(Sales_sum=("Sales", np.sum)).reset_index()
```

**output**

```
    Order ID    Year    Segment   Sales_sum
0   1001        2016    Consumer        300
```